# how to create table that one of the column is point on key of other table ?

Tags: sql, database

I have 4 table on my database

- Table1 : Student courses ( table that contain on string that represent the course name )
- Table2 : StudentGroup ( collection of student group name )
- Table3 : Students ( collection of Student name ( column1 ) and StudentGroup ( column2 ) - the key is combination Student name & StudentGroup)
- Table4 : Student courses ( column1 is AUTO_INCREMENT int , column2 is student key from table3 and column3 is the course that this student study)

My question..

How do i define the table4 ?
How to define the column2 of this table on the 'create table' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for this.

Your tables are not [**normalized**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) this way, you can do this instead:

**`Courses`**:

- `Id` Primary key,
- `Name`.

**`Groups`**:

- `Id` primary key,
- `Name`.

**`Students`**:

- `Id` Primary key,
- `Name`.

**`StudentsGroups`**:

- `Id` Primary key ([surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)).
- `StudentId` foreign key to students table.
- `Groupid` foreign key to groups table.

**`StudentsCourses`**:

- `Id` primary key surrogate key,
- `StudentsId` foreign key to students table,
- `courseid` foreign key to courses tables.

Comment: sorry .. this is my first time i deal with databases .. :: do you mean that i will have 5 tables according to what you said above ?